# How do I get the value of a input form element after an OnKeyPress event?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

How do I obtain the value of a textbox after an OnKeyPress event? For example, Let's say I have the following code:

```
<input type = "number" id = "foo" onKeyPress = "submit();"/>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function submit()
{
var textValue = document.getElementById("foo").value;
alert(textValue);
}
</script>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work because after the `OnKeyPress` is triggered, the variable `textValue` will still be one character behind. I would use `OnKeyUp`, but sadly it doesn't work on Android devices unless the `<input type = "text">` which doesn't work in my situation... Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: Sadly, I have and that doesn't work either...

Comment: Thanks for everyones help! The problem has been solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only problem is Android devices, I suggest using onkeyup for everyone else. Then you can detect if it's android (or if keyup is supported on the input) and, if necessary, implement an Android specific solution.

```
function submit(){
    function submitNow() {
        var textValue = document.getElementById("foo").value;
        alert(textValue);
    }   
    if(isAndroid) {
        setTimeout(submitNow, 10);
    }
    else {
        submitNow() ;
    }
}

var isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1; 
var eventType = (isAndroid) ? "keyup" : "keypress" ;
document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener(EventType, submit);
```

You can then remove the `onKeyPress = "submit();"` from your input.

When not on Android, this code will act normally, using the keyup event. When the client is on Android, it will wait for 1/100th of a second, enough time for the input to update, but too short to be noticeable.

Normally, I'd warn against long key presses, but I'm not aware of an Android keyboard that supports them.

### Android solution only:

```
function submit(){
    function submitNow() {
        var textValue = document.getElementById("foo").value;
        alert(textValue);
    }   
    setTimeout(submitNow, 10);
}

document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("keyup", submit);
```

You could even keep your `onKeyPress = "submit();"` if you really felt like it. Just remove the last line here.

Comment: This app is targeted for just Android devices right now, so most of it won't be necessary. The only reason I found out that this only doesn't work for Android is that the Android emulator is incredibly slow so I just use the Iphone and Ipad emulator instead, but when I tried to transfer the code I came across this error.

Comment: I've added that to my answer. And you can always fiddle with the timeout interval. I'd be interested to know how it goes.

Comment: If this works I will be super happy yet sad... I tried something like this earlier, but instead of doing `setTimeout(submitNow, 10);` I did `setTimeout(submitNow(), 10);`... T.T Well, I'll let you know as soon as the emulator loads!

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem was because i had the `()` at the end the first time :\ Anyways, thank you for your awesome answer! Is there a way to give you more karma or something like that?

Comment: I'm happy it helped. in future, if you want/need brackets in a setTimeout, wrap it in a function eg. `setTimeout(function(){submitNow()}, 10);`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the `input` event instead, which fires after any change to the input's value (via typed characters, delete, paste and drag-and-drop, for example). This will work on all major browsers except IE < 9.

```
document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("input", function() {
    alert("CHANGED!");
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

try following code

```
<input type = "number" id = "foo" onKeyPress = "submit(this);"/>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    function submit(e) {
      alert(e.value);
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using jQuery?

To add jQuery to you page simply put
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the head of your page.

Then to perform the action you required use the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#my_field").keydown (function (e) {
      alert ($(this).val());
  });
</script>
```

Where #myField is the id of your field.

N.B You will no longer need the keypress event in your input.

Comment: I am assuming that this will require internet connection... I am trying to get this to work offline so I don't think this is the right solution for me. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: just get some "offline" jquery file :)

Comment: Well you could download jQuery and include the file itself.  http://jquery.com/.  But this seems like overkill for your issue.

Comment: I agree with @AlexMA I'm sure there is a simple solution I am yet to come across.

Comment: Yes it would be overkill for this issue however jQuery or another framework would be a sensible include though as it will reduce the code you have to write in the long run (jQuery solution is 5 lines plus include where as chosen answer is rather hacky and ~25 lines). And yes it's simple to download the jQuery file itself and include it in the project.